# Boolean return value not accepted in prime check method

Tags: java

I am a java beginner but I have a bit of experience in python. To learn more, I try to recreate some of the things I did in python in java to see how it is different. My idea: create a method that checks whether a given integer parameter is a prime number. Again, this can probably be done easier/more efficient etc., but I see it as a training exercise. This is why I do it with two different for loops (so just for the sake of using for loops :) ).
However, I want the method to return true or false.
When I declare it as in my code below, I get an exception (unsresolved compilation problem), because my method should return a boolean value.
If I change the method to void, I get an error saying my method isn't supposed to return anything.

So what is it... is it returning something or not? And why does this not count as returning a boolean?

I use Win10 and the eclipse IDE.

Thank you!

PS: This is also to try out how to properly set up arrays, as I have zero experience with them.

The Code:

```
public class AB4Funk {
    public static boolean ab40(int n) {
        int x = n/2+1;
        int[] array = new int[x];
        for(int i=2; i<x; i++) {
            array[i-2]=i;
        }
        for(int zahl : array) {
            if(n%zahl==0) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    
    }
}
```

After some very helpful comments, my new code is:

```
public class AB4Funk {
    public static boolean ab40(int n) {
        //int x = n/2+1;
        int[] array = new int[n];
        for(int i=2; i<n; i++) {
            array[i-2]=i;
        }
        for(int zahl : array) {
            if(n%zahl==0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
        
    }
}
```

Which gives me a division by zero error, which I cannot locate. (for debugging I commented out the x (which I don't really need anyways) to see if it is the source of my error)

Comment: You have to consider the case that someone passes 0 into that method so that an empy array is created and your loops never run.

Comment: The `return false` should be _after_ the loop. Right now, you return `false` for any number that is not evenly divisible by _any_ number. (This will also resolve the compilation error.) Also, you may want to invert `true` and `false` if you want the check whether the number _is_ a prime.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS or 1 or 2, that will result in `x` being 0 because integer division.

Comment: Think about it, on the first number `zahl` in every case someting is returned. I would have expected for-if-return false, at the end return true.

Comment: Thank you for all of your suggestions!
I changed true/false (which makes sense, obviously...) and now I have a loop that returns false if it finds any number by which my n is evenly divisible and if nothing happens, it returns true after the loop.
So far so good, but now I get a division by zero error, even though there is no zero in my method.
I see the point of checking n for the wrong input, but as this is only my training method for just myself, I just accept this.

Comment: Also: think about whether you really need `array`.

Comment: @D.Goldberg I strongly encourage you to set some breakpoints and try to debug your code yourself.

Comment: You never assign values to your last two elements in the array, so they are zero. Highly recommended not to use an array at all, it's not needed.

Comment: Oh, now that makes sense!
As I said, I have zero experience with arrays and this exercise was just for me to get familiar with them. But I understand that in the real world I would not use one in this case and that the two 0s at the end are the main problem here. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main problems with your method:

- it is possible that the loop is never executed, e.g. if the input number is smaller than 2, thus resulting in the method never returning anything
- if the loop is executed, the method will return `true` or `false` after the very first iteration, i.e. after testing the first potential divisor

You can fix both problem by moving the `return false` after the loop, i.e. if the number is not evenly divisible by *any* of those numbers.

Also, you may consider inverting `true` and `false`, since you want to test whether a number *is* prime, and also call your method accordingly. Finally, you do not have to store all the potential divisors in an array first but can just test them directly.

```
public static boolean prime(int n) {
    int x = n/2+1; // actually, testing until x = sqrt(n) would be enough
    for (int zahl = 2; zahl < x, zahl++) {
        if (n % zahl == 0) {
            return false; // not prime
        }
    }
    return true; // is prime
}
```

As mentioned in comments, you may also want to change the upper bound `x` for numbers to test from `n/2` to `sqrt(n)` (or, conversely, change the check in the loop to `zahl * zahl <= n`). After all, if the number is evenly divisible by a number `> sqrt(n)`, it also has to be evenly divisible by a number `< sqrt(n)`. This may seem like a minor improvement, like skipping even divisors after having tested for 2, but it's actually equivalent to changing an O(n²) algorithms to O(n) and quite significant for testing larger numbers.

Comment: Perhaps worth pointing out too that `zahl <= sqrt(n)` (or `zahl*zahl <= n`) is a tighter bound than `zahl < x`.

Comment: @AndyTurner I did not want to overdo it, but you are right of course.

Comment: Thank you, that code is much better than mine! The true/false thing was just me being a bit too tired :D But getting rid of the array altogether and putting the return after the loop fixes all my problems!